# why matlab out of memory using mex

Tags: c, matlab, opengl, memory-leaks, mex

Matlab would be out of memory, if i use a mex file in a loop. I think it's caused by memory leak. mxMalloc variable is freed by mxFree, but I cannot destroy mxCreateNumericArray variable using mxDestroyArray(plhs[0]).

The mex file is from Offscreen toolbox [link](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25071-matlab-offscreen-rendering-toolbox) . The code is as following.

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "OffscreenGL.h"
#include "OffscreenCommon.h"
void drawPatchAndConvert(GLuint listName, GLubyte *imageBuffer, unsigned int imgHeight, unsigned int imgWidth, unsigned int zoomFactor = 1)
{
      // This is a temporary bug fix for Nvidia's open program
      // seems the width of the pixel has to be a multiple of 4
      // for other width, we have to pad the width and remove it later
     unsigned int paddedWidth = imgWidth * zoomFactor % 4;
     if (paddedWidth != 0){
         paddedWidth = 4 - paddedWidth + imgWidth * zoomFactor;
     }else {
        paddedWidth = imgWidth * zoomFactor;
     }

     unsigned char *paddedImgBuffer = (unsigned char *)mxMalloc(paddedWidth * imgHeight * zoomFactor * MAX_COLOR_CHANNEL * sizeof(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE));
    drawPatch(listName, paddedImgBuffer, imgHeight, imgWidth, zoomFactor);  
    // reorder the pixel data for the opengl to matlab conversion
    unsigned int imgSize = imgHeight * imgWidth * zoomFactor * zoomFactor;
    unsigned int imgSize2 = imgSize * 2;
    unsigned int matlabImgIndex = 0;
    unsigned int oglImageIndex = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < imgWidth * zoomFactor; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < imgHeight * zoomFactor; i++, matlabImgIndex++) {
            oglImageIndex = (j + (imgHeight*zoomFactor -1-i) * paddedWidth) * 3;
            imageBuffer[matlabImgIndex] = paddedImgBuffer[oglImageIndex];
            imageBuffer[matlabImgIndex + imgSize] = paddedImgBuffer[oglImageIndex + 1];
            imageBuffer[matlabImgIndex + imgSize2] = paddedImgBuffer[oglImageIndex + 2];
        }
    }
    mxFree(paddedImgBuffer);
}

static void renderColorMesh(double *FM, int fNum, double *VM, int vNum, float *ColorM, int colorNum,const mxArray *CamParamS, double *imgSizeV, double *zNearFarV, unsigned int zoomFactor,unsigned char *imgBuffer)
{
      cameraSetup(CamParamS, zNearFarV[0], zNearFarV[1], (unsigned int) imgSizeV[0],  (unsigned int) imgSizeV[1], zoomFactor);
   #ifndef NDEBUG
    mexPrintf("Start to create the display list: fNum=%d, vNum=%d, colorNum=%d\n", fNum, vNum, colorNum);
   #endif
    GLuint list = createDisplayListWithColor(FM, fNum, VM, vNum, ColorM, colorNum);

   #ifndef NDEBUG
    mexPrintf("Start to draw the patch\n");
   #endif
    drawPatchAndConvert(list, imgBuffer, (int) imgSizeV[0], (int) imgSizeV[1], zoomFactor);
}


void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    // get the vertex array, face array, and color array
    double *FM = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    int fNum = mxGetM(prhs[0]); 
    double *VM = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
    int vNum = mxGetM(prhs[1]);
    float *ColorM = (float *)mxGetData(prhs[2]);
    int colorNum = mxGetM(prhs[2]);

    // get the camera parameters
    const mxArray *CamParamS = prhs[3];
    double *imgSizeV = mxGetPr(prhs[4]);
    double *zNearFarV = mxGetPr(prhs[5]);
    double zoomFactor = mxGetScalar(prhs[6]);

    OffscreenGL offscreenGL((int)(imgSizeV[0] * zoomFactor), (int) (imgSizeV[1] * zoomFactor));
    int output3Size[3];

    unsigned char *imgBuffer;

    if (offscreenGL.RGB8Setup()) {
        //mexPrintf("OpenGLCanvas setup Successful\n");
        output3Size[0] = (int) (imgSizeV[0] * zoomFactor);
        output3Size[1] = (int) (imgSizeV[1] * zoomFactor);
        output3Size[2] = 3;

        plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericArray(3, output3Size, mxUINT8_CLASS, mxREAL);
        imgBuffer = (unsigned char *) mxGetData(plhs[0]);
        renderColorMesh(FM, fNum, VM, vNum, ColorM, colorNum, CamParamS, imgSizeV,
                        zNearFarV, (unsigned int) zoomFactor, imgBuffer);

    } else {
        mexPrintf("OpenGLCanvas setup failed\n");       
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no call to `mxDestroyArray` in the code you show? Also if you call eg `x = mxCreateNumericArray(...)`, the logical step to free it would be `mxDestroyArray( x )` and not `mxDestroyArray( x[ 0 ] )`

Comment: @stijn: that line creates the LHS output of the MEX-function, so obviously you should not destroy if you want to return the result to MATLAB. user2613981: I dont see any obvious memory leaks, I'm thinking the library you're using is the culprit, not your code...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. @Amro is right that it is not because of this MEX file. It is because of a function used by this file,

  'GLuint list = createDisplayListWithColor(FM, fNum, VM, vNum, ColorM, colorNum);'
It is the problem of openGL as following in the function of createDisplayListWithColor.

' glColor3f(ColorM[vIndex], ColorM[vIndex + vNum], ColorM[vIndex + vNum2]); '

But i do not know how glColor3f causes memory leak. I used glClear at the end, but cannot solve it.

Comment: @user2613981: you should post that as an answer if it solved your problem. On another note, when you have this sort of problem in the future, an easy first-thing to try is to use `mxMalloc` instead of `malloc`, that way allocated memory is registered with the MATLAB memory manager and is automatically freed when MEX-function exits (in case you forgot to manually `mxFree` it)

Comment: ok I just saw your 2nd comment, maybe this is not yet solved.. I havent yet looked at the toolbox code, so I cant say where exactly is the memory leak in that function. For now I suggest you attach a debugger and step through the C code, maybe you could spot the problem that way...

Comment: @Amro Thanks for your suggestion. I think I'd better post another post for the problem of openGL.

Answer (score 0):

This line is suspicious:

```
    paddedWidth = 4 - paddedWidth + imgWidth * zoomFactor;
```

It only pads the entire zoomed in line with a few bytes. I think you meant something like

```
     paddedWidth = (4 - paddedWidth + imgWidth) * zoomFactor;
```